# Excel VBA sort multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I would like to sort every row with data from column A to S in ascending order, total 5580 rows. Moving forward, the number of rows will increase.

I have tried to record the sort actions for 1st 2 rows. Then I attempted to merge the code to sort from 1st row to the 39th row as a trial, but failed.

```
Sub Macro4()

Macro4 Macro

Rows("13:39").Select

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)").Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A13:S39"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A13:S" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply

End With

Rows("14:14").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A14:S14"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A14:S14")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
     End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be the way to go I think

```
For Each rw In Range("a1:E3").Rows

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(rw.Address), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range(rw.Address)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Next rw
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but it doesn't work... Do i need to amend something like  "rw.Address"?